# Angular Behavior Subject called mulitple times in infinite scroll

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular9, angular2-observables

I am using angular behavior subject to emit the values between the two child components.Those components are part of in infinite page (parent component) scroll. my problem here is, in single click behavior subject mulitple times calling ngonit so i have tried in several ways to solve this issue but i can't. Below is my code:

Emiiter Service:

```
export class emitDataService {
  private productColorUpdate = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
  private productVariantUpate = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
  getCurrentProductColor = this.productColorUpdate.asObservable();
  getProductVariantUpdate = this.productVariantUpate.asObservable();
  
  emitValue(value: string, values: string) {
    this.productColorUpdate.next({ value, values });
  }

  emitVariantValue(prod: string, prodcode: string, prodcolor: string) {
    this.productVariantUpate.next({ prodvariant, prodcode, prodcolor });
  }
}
```

component 1:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.sub =  this.emitDataService.getCurrentProductColor
      .subscribe((data) => {
        if (data) {
          this.someMethod(data);
        }
      });
  }
  someMethod():void {
   
  }
  clicks(data):void{
  //mylogic goes here at the end of the statement i trigger the emit
     this.customDataService.emitVariantValue(prodcode, prodvalue, prodcolor);
  }
```

Component 2:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.sub =  this.emitDataService.emitVariantValue.subscribe((data) => {
      if (data) {
        this.somePrivateMethod(data);
      }
    });
  }
  somePrivateMethod() : void{
  
  }
  triggerEmits():void {
  this.customDataService.emitValue(prodcolor, prodcode);
  }
```

If I am using Unsubscribe in ng onit or in ngchanges it does not trigger in first click like below:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
      this.sub =  this.emitDataService.getCurrentProductColor
          .subscribe((data) => {
            if (data) {
              this.someMethod(data);
            }
          }).unsubscribe();
      }
```

Since the parent component using ngdestroy so it didn't call this page ngdestroy. Kindly help me to figure out this issue to avoid multiple calls in ngonit

Comment: A service isn't necessary if the data is just moving from child to parent. Read up on component outputs. Their defined as an EventEmitter which is an extension of a rxjs Subject. Emit the clicks from the child component, and in the parent have all events trigger the same method.

Comment: @diclo- can you give some example or share some links

Comment: What is your html code to display the child components? I think it has something to do with Change Detection in Angular.

Answer (score 0):

> in single click behavior subject mulitple times calling ngonit

The event isn't triggering `ngOnInit()`. You are subscribing to the service observable in these components that render in this infinite scroller. RxJS subscriptions will remain active until you unsubscribe.

So as each component is instantiated, they all subscribe to your service observable. When you click on one component to emit a new Subject value, all the components subscribed to its observable receive the new value.

The reason your `unsubscribe()` code example doesn't work is because it is subscribing, then immediately unsubscribing.

If your requirement is to have each separate pair of `Component 1` and `Component 2` talking to each other, you may need to have them encapsulated inside a parent component. This parent component's logic would be identical to your service. But instead of having all components subscribe to the service, you have each pair of `Component 1` and `Component 2` subscribing to their respective parent component.